# Сравнение string и массива string

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Как можно первый символ текста сдвинуть "назад по алфавиту" (например б=а, к=й, а=я), а второй символ текста сдвинуть "вперёд по алфавиту" (а=б, й=к, я=а)? Пример текста : Доброго времени суток. = Гпасндн бсдндоз рфспл.

Пытался использовать массив string, в котором хранил весь алфавит, а после циклом for прогонял все символы и сравнивал их с символами в тексте, но ничего не получилось. Выводит что попало...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String text = "Доброго времени суток.";
        int text_length = text.length();

        String [][] alphabet = {{"а","б","в","г","д","е","ё"},
                                {"ж","з","и","й","к","л","м"},
                                {"н","о","п","р","с","т","у"},
                                {"ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ"},
                                {"ы","ь","э","ю","я", null, null},
        };

        int column = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;

        char char_x;
        char char_y;

        String string_x =0;

        int move = 1;

        while (counter < text_length) {

            char_x = text.charAt(x);
            string_x =String.valueOf(char_x);

            for (int i =1;i<=33;i++ ) {
                if (string_x.equals(alphabet[row][column])) {

                    if (move % 2 != 0) {
                        if (!string_x.equals(alphabet[0][0])) {

                            result.append(alphabet[row][column-1]);

                        } else {
                            result.append(alphabet[4][4]);
                        }

                    } else {

                        if (move % 2 == 0) {
                            if (!string_x.equals(alphabet[4][4])) {

                                result.append(alphabet[row][column+1]);

                            } else {
                                result.append(alphabet[0][0]);

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (column !=6) {
                    column ++;
                } else {
                    if (row !=4) {
                        row ++;
                        column = 0;
                    }
                }

                move++;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это что, Java?.

Comment: @S.H. вы что-то перепутали,это не шарп.

Comment: @aepot - Прошу прощения, облажался как обычно :-)

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы сильно усложнили себе жизнь, сделав alphabet двумерным массивом. Теперь Вам приходится возиться со строкамии столбцами, а в случае одномерного массива Вам пришлось бы иметь дело только с индексом в этом массиве. И еще - если Вы укажете язык в тегах вопроса - то любители ответить, типа меня, слетятся на него, просто как мухи на... на мёд!

Comment: @S.H. Возможно и усложнил, не буду спорить =) Тег добавил.

Comment: Вариантов много: обращаться к массиву алфавита, с проверкой большая это буква или маленькая (а значит массивов 2), проверять выходит ли значение за массив при сдвиге, если да, то присваивать первый\последний элемент. Можно просто сдвигать char (там целое число, можно просто прибавлять или убавлять). Но тут учтите уникальные символы русского алфавита (смотрите таблицу символов) и тд

Comment: @wigravy Уникальные символы должны оставаться неизменными. Только буквы должны подвергнуться изменениям.

Comment: @Индюк речь не шла об уникальных символах, а о позиции некоторых букв в таблицах если сдвигать char.

Comment: @wigravy, а, понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения такой задачи нужно прежде всего определить функции для возврата следующего/предыдущего символа для данной *буквы*, и по очереди вызывать один из данных методов.  Также, понадобится счётчик букв в слове, который будет сбрасываться при появлении небуквенного символа.

```java
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cnt = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sb.append(cnt++ % 2 == 1 ? next(c) : prev(c));
        } else {
            cnt = 0;
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Для дешифровки соответственно достаточно будет изменить порядок вызова `next/prev`:

```java
public static String decrypt(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cnt = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sb.append(cnt++ % 2 == 0 ? next(c) : prev(c));
        } else {
            cnt = 0;
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Методы `next(char c), prev(char c)` можно определить и без массива, при помощи `switch` (на Java 12+ будет выглядеть ещё лаконичнее):

```java
private static char next(char c) {
    switch(c) {
       case 'z' : return 'a';
       case 'Z' : return 'A';
       case 'я' : return 'а';
       case 'е' : return 'ё';
       case 'ё' : return 'ж';
       case 'Я' : return 'А';
       case 'Е' : return 'Ё';
       case 'Ё' : return 'Ж';
       default  : return (char) (c + 1);       
    }
/** // Java 12
    return switch(c) {
       case 'z' -> 'a';
       case 'Z' -> 'A';
       case 'я' -> 'а';
       case 'Я' -> 'А';
       default  -> (char) (c + 1);       
    };
*/
}

private static char prev(char c) {
    switch(c) {
       case 'a' : return 'z';
       case 'A' : return 'Z';
       case 'а' : return 'я';
       case 'А' : return 'Я';
       case 'ё' : return 'е';
       case 'ж' : return 'ё';
       case 'Ё' : return 'Е';
       case 'Ж' : return 'Ё';
       default  : return (char) (c - 1);
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
String s = encrypt("Доброго времени суток! АБВГДейка! Где ёж? Вышел весь!");
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(decrypt(s));
```

Вывод:

```
Гпасндн бсдндоз рфспй! ЯВБДГёиля! Вед ез? Бьчёк бёрэ!
Доброго времени суток! АБВГДейка! Где ёж? Вышел весь!
```

В слове `"суток"` `к` должно перейти в *предыдущую* букву.

Comment: При дешифровке иногда первые и последние буквы принимают неправильные значения.

Comment: А если точнее, то я немного модернизировал Ваш код, чтобы он умел дешифровать, просто изменив в `prev(char c)` на `default  : return (char) (c + 1);`  и в  `next(char c)` на `default  : return (char) (c -1);`

Comment: @Индюк, я не совсем понял, при чём тут _дешифровка_, если задача была о _шифровке_ входящего сообщения. :)  Для _обратной_ задачи дешифровки не имело смысла менять рабочие методы `next` / `prev`, достаточно было изменить условие их вызова: `sb.append(cnt++ % 2 == 0 ? next(c) : prev(c));`

Comment: @Отлично, теперь работает =)

Comment: Я ещё добавил корректную замену для `ё/Ё`

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, не знаю Java, напишу решение на php с комментариями, думаю, сможете адаптировать. Соглашусь с  [S.H.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205151/s-h) , вы сильно усложняете двумерным массивом. Попробуйте так:

```
$string = "Доброго времени суток.";
// разбиваем строку на массив символов
$strArr = mb_str_split($string);
$letterString = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
//массив букв
$array = mb_str_split($letterString);

//boolean для смены значения
$change = true;
//измененная строка
$string2 = '';

foreach ($strArr as $i => $value)
{
    //символ есть в массиве символов, продолжаем
    if(in_array($value, $array))
    {
        //проверяем не "а" ли, если да
        if($strArr[$i] == "а")
        {
            //Заменяем на -1, т.е. "я"
            if($change)
            {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[32];
                $change = false;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            //Заменяем на +1, "б"
            } else {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[1];
                $change = true;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        //проверяем на "А"
        } elseif($strArr[$i] == "А") {
            //Заменяем на "Я"
            if($change)
            {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[65];
                $change = false;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            //Заменяем на +1, "Б"
            } else {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[34];
                $change = true;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        //проверяем на "я"
        } elseif($strArr[$i] == "я") {
            //Заменяем на "ю"
            if($change)
            {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[31];
                $change = false;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            //Заменяем на +1, "а"
            } else {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[0];
                $change = true;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        //проверяем на "Я"
        } elseif($strArr[$i] == "Я") {
            //Заменяем на "Ю"
            if($change)
            {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[64];
                $change = false;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            //Заменяем на +1, "А"
            } else {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[33];
                $change = true;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        // если не "аАяЯ", то
        } else {
            if($change)
            {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[array_search($strArr[$i], $array) -1];
                $change = false;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            } elseif (!$change) {
                $strArr[$i] = $array[array_search($strArr[$i], $array) +1];
                $change = true;
                $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
                continue;
            }
        }
    // Не находим, значит добавляем так (это запятые, точки, и т.д.)
    } else {
        $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
        continue;
    }
}
```

Вывод построчный (Буква слова, буква замены, позиция замены):

```
Д => Г = -1
о => п = +1
б => а = -1
р => с = +1
о => н = -1
г => д = +1
о => н = -1
в => б = +1
р => п = -1
е => ё = +1
м => л = -1
е => ё = +1
н => м = -1
и => й = +1
с => р = -1
у => ф = +1
т => с = -1
о => п = +1
к => й = -1
```

Полная строка:

```
Гпасндн бпёлёмй рфспй.
```

Используемые функции php:

mb_str_split - Если задана многобайтовая строка возвращает массив символов

in_array — Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве значение

array_search — Осуществляет поиск данного значения в массиве и возвращает ключ первого найденного элемента в случае успешного выполнения

P.S. Если необходимо ***всегда*** сменять +/- $change, при ***любых*** символах, можно ввести доп. проверку. Дополним:

```
} else {
    $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
    continue;
}
```

вот так:

```
} else {
    $string2 = $string2 . $strArr[$i];
    if($change)
    {
        $change = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $change = true;
    }
    continue;
}
```

И получится вывод строки:

```
Гпасндн бсдндоз рфспй.
```

Comment: Поставил Вашему решению "плюсик за смелость". Я перед этим тоже написал решение на C# - в несколько строк, благодаря linq - но не решился его выкладывать :-)

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо :-)

Comment: @HMRDevil, спасибо за помощь, но я всё же выбрал второй ответ, так как в php не силён =)

Comment: @Индюк Не за что